# Get offset minutes from timezone (string) with NodaTime

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

What's the easiest way to get the minutes if I only have a string that represents the timezone? (for example "Europe/London")

So far I have:

```
public static int ConvertFromTimeZoneToMinutesOffset(string timeZone)
{
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];

    // Need magic code to get offset as minutes
}
```

But I'm not finding an easy approach to convert it to minutes.

NOTE: What I need is the offset in that specific moment in which the code is being executed. Between that timezone and UTC.

Comment: What offset? It varies over time. Right now it's 60 minutes, but on October 30th it will go back to 0...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I mean the offset in that specific moment in which the code is being executed. Between that timezone and UTC.

Comment: Right - please update the question to indicate that.

Comment: Done. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need [`DateTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(Instant)`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_DateTimeZone_GetUtcOffset.htm):

```
public static int ConvertFromTimeZoneToMinutesOffset(string timeZone, IClock clock)
{
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
    Offset offset = zone.GetUtcOffset(clock.Now);
    return offset.Milliseconds / NodaConstants.MillisecondsPerMinute;
}
```

You *could* leave off the `IClock` parameter and instead use `SystemClock.Instance` in the method, but that leads to code which is harder to test.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Skeet.

Comment: @AxelPrieto: I've just edited it btw, as otherwise you'd end up having to cast the result to `int`.

Comment: I believe that should be NodaConstants (with an s), in case anyone gets an error.

Comment: For NodaTime 2.0 use `clock.GetCurrentInstant()` in place of `clock.Now`

Answer (score -2):

Use the DatePart() function on minutes.

Comment: That's not enough. I don't have a "DateTime", I have a TimeZone. And I need the minutes, so instead of "America/Buenos Aires" I need -90 (the offset in minutes)